# Python: Cast Dictionary to Tuple implicit by calling a method

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I have a problem with Code from the Mininet open source project. I abstracted it to the following scenario:

```
def bar (*a, **b):
    b.update({'a':(a,)})
    foo(**b)

def foo (*a, **c):
    print(c)
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar(2,3,4, x=3, y=5)
```

Method bar is only a helper to create a function call of foo.
If I run it, print(a) has no output, because the values are still stored in the dictionary b. If I change *a to a, it works fine.

**And here my question**:
Is there a possibility which does not modify the Method foo which puts data into *a with data and the call of foo is like in line 3? This means only b in method bar is allowed to be modified.

Comment: You could just do `def bar(*a, **b): foo(a=a, **b)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to comply both your conditions.

If the method `foo` stays the same the parameter `*a` represents a **list** of arguments with no name (like `bar(2,3,4)` in your example). And the call to `foo(**b)` in line 3 means passing keyword args (like `bar(x=3, y=5)` in your example) so they will be passed to `**c` as it is the keyword argument in `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I want to make you understand instead of just giving the answer because StackOverflow is all about explaining the concept instead of writing code, let's understand few points :

*args and **kwargs are use as arbitrary number of arguments.

> Kwargs ** syntax requires a mapping (such as a dictionary); each
>   key-value pair in the mapping becomes a keyword argument.

***while***

> *args recieves a tuple containing the positional arguments.

Now let's take simple example to understand your problem:

```
def check(*a,**b):
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Now *a require a tuple or list or positional argument while **b require dict format keyworded argument.

One more point before jumping into the problem:

> *l idiom is to unpack argument lists,tuples,set

```
a,*b=(1,2,3,4,5)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**output:**

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now if i call that function something like:

```
def check(*a,**b):
    print("value_a {}".format(a))
    print("value_b {}".format(b))


print(check({'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'a': 5,'r':56}))
```

Now *a will take the value because there is no keyworded argument :

```
value_a ({'x': 3, 'y': 5, 'a': 5, 'r': 56},)
```

But let's add few keywords argument:

```
print(check({'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'a': 5,'r':56},key_s=5,values=10))
```

**output:**

```
value_a ({'a': 5, 'y': 5, 'r': 56, 'x': 3},)
value_b {'key_s': 5, 'values': 10}
```

Let's start using unpack method :

```
print(check(*{'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'a': 5,'r':56}))
```

**output will be:**

```
value_a ('r', 'x', 'y', 'a')
value_b {}
None
```

Because as i shown you * will unpack the keys of dict and it will treat them as the positional argument not keyworded argument.

Now let's use ** unpacking which will unpack dict as key,value pairs :

I think you got the point , Now let's use ** for mapping dict so it will unpack the dict and each key, value will be keyword argument :

```
print(check(**{'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'a': 5,'r':56}))
```

**output:**

```
value_a ()
value_b {'y': 5, 'r': 56, 'a': 5, 'x': 3}
```

So everything is clear now I think.

**Now let's back to your problem :**

As you said if you are using:

```
def check(a,**b):
    print("value_a {}".format(a))
    print("value_b {}".format(b))


print(check(**{'y': 5, 'x': 3, 'a': 5,'r':56}))
```

You are getting result because it's taking 'a' value from dict , and rest of values are taken by **b

Now if you want to use *a and **b then you have to provide :

```
the positional argument for *a
Keyworded argument for **b
```

As you said you don't want to modify foo then, You can try something like this:

```
def bar (*a, **b):
    foo((a,),**b)


def foo (*a, **c):
    print(c)
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar(2,3,4, x=3, y=5)
```

**output:**

```
{'y': 5, 'x': 3}
(((2, 3, 4),),)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer; i confirm your presentation completely. thanks for that.
My problem is the second condition:
foo(**b) should not be changed
is this possible too